# "Head state missing, repairing" after private network crash. Any way to recover the blocks?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, synchronization

I'm running a small PoA private network (2 nodes, one signer, one for API purposes). Yesterday, the system both nodes are running on crashed due to an unrelated issue. As a result, both geth instances had an unclean shutdown. After attempting to boot the signer node, I got the message that the head state was missing, and the chain rewound to the last time geth was started (block 669120). Both nodes were operating on a full sync, and I have backups of the data taken before and after the crash.

Is there any way to restart the chain from the most recent full block (872186)? I found [this thread](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/19124) on the go-ethereum github, where they suggest exporting block data and importing it on a new node.

I attempted to export the data using a backup of the API client. It notes that it has block 872186 as the latest full block, but then rewinds back to the last fast-sync pivot marker (even though it operates on a full sync?). Output attached below.

geth v1.10.13 (latest at time of writing)

```
jbyers44:/ssddata/bin$ ./geth --datadir /ssddata/eth/tmp/light --syncmode "full" --cache 2048 export /ssddata/eth/tmp/backup.rlp 0 872185
INFO [11-27|21:42:38.618] Maximum peer count                       ETH=50 LES=0 total=50
INFO [11-27|21:42:38.618] Smartcard socket not found, disabling    err="stat /run/pcscd/pcscd.comm: no such file or directory"
INFO [11-27|21:42:38.619] Set global gas cap                       cap=50,000,000
INFO [11-27|21:42:38.619] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/ssddata/eth/tmp/light/geth/chaindata cache=1024.00MiB handles=524,288
INFO [11-27|21:42:40.083] Opened ancient database                  database=/ssddata/eth/tmp/light/geth/chaindata/ancient readonly=false
INFO [11-27|21:42:40.088] Loaded most recent local header          number=872,186 hash=a33719..ef3c3f td=1,744,373 age=7h3m53s
INFO [11-27|21:42:40.088] Loaded most recent local full block      number=872,186 hash=a33719..ef3c3f td=1,744,373 age=7h3m53s
INFO [11-27|21:42:40.088] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=872,186 hash=a33719..ef3c3f td=1,744,373 age=7h3m53s
INFO [11-27|21:42:40.088] Loaded last fast-sync pivot marker       number=668,940
WARN [11-27|21:42:40.088] Head state missing, repairing            number=872,186 hash=a33719..ef3c3f snaproot=e52185..48b357
INFO [11-27|21:42:40.092] Deep froze chain segment                 blocks=2 elapsed=5.698ms number=782,186 hash=7e5098..033f37
INFO [11-27|21:43:10.955] Loaded most recent local header          number=669,120 hash=f92722..d948f9 td=1,338,241 age=3w2d19h
INFO [11-27|21:43:10.955] Loaded most recent local full block      number=669,120 hash=f92722..d948f9 td=1,338,241 age=3w2d19h
INFO [11-27|21:43:10.955] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=669,120 hash=f92722..d948f9 td=1,338,241 age=3w2d19h
INFO [11-27|21:43:10.955] Loaded last fast-sync pivot marker       number=668,940
Fatal: Export error: block number 872185 larger than head block 669120
```